# How to get dynamically session object in struts2

Tags: java, session, struts2, ognl

I am trying to get dynamically session object in struts2 application.

```
<s:if test="%{#session['resToken'].bookingType == 1}">
```

resToken can be get by `<s:property value="%{resToken}">..`

But I can't write `<s:property> within <s:if test="">`

its giving me error of double quotes..

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/booking/banquet/guest-Info-View.jsp(150,40) Unterminated &lt;s:if tag
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you use `${sessionScope.resToken.bookingType == 1}`

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading that right, then the value of `resToken` is actually the name of a session attribute, right? So, try something like: `${sessionScope[resToken].bookingType}`.

Comment: Didn't read all the answers well enough. My answer is the same as yours and yours came first.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to put an `<s:property/>` tag inside of an `<s:if/>` tag isn't the right approach. Both tags take an OGNL expression as their argument. Therefore, if `%{resToken}` is working for one, it should work for the other too.

With that said, `%{#session['resToken'].bookingType}` looks correct. Have you tried outputting the value of that to see what it is? You can also use `%{#session.resToken.bookingType}`. First determine that you are properly referencing the session variable, then make sure that the value really does `==` 1.

Or you can use JSTL/JSP EL like the others suggested and go with:

```
// i don't remember off the top of my head if it should be == or eq
<c:if test="${sessionScope.resToken.bookingType eq 1}"></c:if>
```

[OGNL Reference](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.1/docs/ognl.html)

Comment: I'm not sure what the equivalent OGNL notation is for the EL answer I gave, but I believe that `resToken` needs to be evaluated first and not used as a literal property name.

Comment: You can chain properties such as `sessionScope.resToken.bookingType` in both EL and OGNL. You should beware of nulls, but chaining is supported.

Comment: Understood. Again, maybe I misinterpreted the question, but there's a difference between (EL) `sessionScope.resToken` and `sessionScope[resToken]`.

Comment: @kschneid: Actually, I think that I misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 0):

'resToken' is not equal to resToken, the later is a variable which you seem to want the first is a string.

Simply write:

```
<s:if test="%{#session[resToken].bookingType == 1}">
```

If this does not work please use property tags to output smaller parts of the expression to see what is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten its solution ..

first is set resToken

check setTest 
    Test 11    Test 11